# How to port content from Blogger to Hugo while maximizing SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, blog, blogger

I have an old Google Blogspot website (name.blogspot.com) that I need to port to `Hugo`. `Hugo` has better support for Markdown format and loads of other functionality which I would love for my tech blog (which has code samples and such).

I searched for a seamless way to port my existing content from blogger to hugo, and I [found quite a few plugins allow that](https://gohugo.io/tools/migrations/).

However, my question is what is the most seamless way to do this such that the *search engine rankings* on my new website aren't penalized for duplicate content? If my new website contains pages that are an exact copy of my blog's posts, wouldn't Google's SEO penalize my new website? Is there anyway around this?

And what is the best course of action for the old blog? Remove those posts? OR redirect those links to corresponding pages on my new website? I am looking to understand what my best options are in this scenario to improve SEO for my new website. Ultimately, I'm looking to host those pages on my new `Hugo` website and have all my readers directed there.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the following answer, as Mary rightly pointed out that Blogger doesn't support 301 redirects to other websites. Apparently Blogger's 301 redirect option only supports redirects within the same blogger website.

The only option here seems to be to add a JavaScript redirect or a `meta refresh` redirect, the latter of which can be done by putting the following code in each blogger article's `<head>` tag:

```
<meta content='0; url=https://www.yourhugoblog.example/article-slug/' http-equiv='refresh'/>
```

You'll want to customize the `url` individually for each article, redirecting it to the corresponding article on the new domain. This should take care of both users and search engines, [at least Google](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-meta-refresh-redirects-work-25335.html).

Comment: Blogger's custom re-directs only all redirection from one Blogger post to another one inside the same domain.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ Thank you, I just switched up my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister thanks, does this take care of SEO? Since it's not a 301 permanent redirect, would Google penalize the new blog for duplicate content?